# How to avoid Silverlight application Hanging Problem...?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I developed a Silverlight application with various animations.. While I running my application, it runs better for first 30-45 secs without any problem... After that, It becomes hanging... I am using XP, 32 bit and VS2010 (SL4).. When i reduce my MaxFrameRate value to 10, there is no use.. Still i have the same issue... this is in local as well as in IIS.. So anybody have better idea to overcome this problem... Waiting for your kind help..

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a memory leak, you need to provide more info.  Have you tried using hardware acceleration? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309563%28v=vs.95%29.aspx